# Cannot get list in controller from view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am passing list of object in ajax like this

```
    //things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });
    var postData = { things: things };
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddItemEbayListing", "ReadyItemsListing")',
        data: postData,
        success: function () {
            $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
```

and here is my controller code

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult AddItemEbayListing(List<FixedPriceItemObj> things)
    { 
        return Json(true);
    }
```

This is my model class

Here is the data that I get in postData variable
[image]

```
    public class FixedPriceItemObj
    {
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public double Start_Price { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't know what is the problem but I can not get data in controller variable 'things'. I have tried many solutions but there is some mistake I could not see

Comment: You have to use `JSON.stringify(postData)` like this way : `data: JSON.stringify(postData)` because you are sending data as `json`

Comment: Alternatively, remove `contentType: 'application/json;` and continue to not send as json.  They need to match either way (either both json or neither json)

Comment: when I use [FromBody] in the controller. I receive null. When I don't use this I get Count   = 0 in param

Answer (score 0):

since contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' is used,replace

```
 var postData = { things: things };
```

with

```
  var postData =  JSON.stringify(things);
```

and add [FromBody] to action

```
 [HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult AddItemEbayListing([FromBody]List<FixedPriceItemObj> things)
    { 
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can try to remove contentType: 'application/json; but I would not recommend it since application/json should be the first choice selection for performance.

Comment: Forgive me if i'm wrong but I dont think you need `[FromBody]` in ASP.NET-MVC

Comment: @JamesS  it is certainly needed  since  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',  it would not be needed for another content type. I updated my answer